# Hide Customizer's Widget Choices From The List

Tags: customization, theme-customizer

Is there a way to hide a few selected widgets (E.g.: `Calendar` & `Recent Comment`) from the Customizer's list using my child's theme `functions.php` or `style.css`. Refer to the screenshot below:

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to disable a Widget from appearing in this list is to unregister it. You can do that just in the customizer:

```
function unregister_customizer_widgets() {
    if ( is_customize_preview() ){
        unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Recent_Posts');
    }
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'unregister_customizer_widgets' );
```

**But** that will remove it from the page preview and the sidebars. Even if it is used somewhere on the page it will not be displayed, that is not a very useful solution. You could check if the widget has been used by looking in the `sidebars_widgets` option and hide it only if it had not been used, but again it is not very good solution.

---

Your best option here is to hide it with CSS and enqueue stylesheet only for the customizer:

```
function my_customize_preview_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'new_customizer_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/customizer-style.css' );
}
add_action( 'customize_controls_print_styles', 'my_customize_preview_style' );
```

Inside it hide the desired widgets and remember about `!important` as they all have inline `display: block;`.

But consider again if you have to hide the widget from the user, displaying in in one place and hiding in the other will be confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've created the CSS file with the code below but it's not working. Any pointers?

#available-menu-items .item-tpl, #available-widgets .widget-tpl .widget-tpl-calendar-1.widget-tpl.calendar-1 {
  display: none !important;
}

Comment: And I tried with this code below as well:
#widget-tpl-calendar-1.widget-tpl.calendar-1 {
  display: none !important;
 
}

Comment: Try: `[id^="widget-tpl-calendar-"] { display: none !important; }` for the calendar. If it is not working in chrome you can press F12 go to the Network tab, refresh the page and see if the new css file is shown there.

Comment: Thanks! It's working. And I had to change get_template_directory_uri() to get_stylesheet_directory_uri() within my functions.php as I'm using a child theme.